# How to save the output of a if statement in a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
a = [] ;

if yn_key == 'y' and KeyResp.keys == 'y':
    a = 1;
elif yn_key == 'n' and KeyResp.keys == 'n':
    a = 1;
else:
    a = 0;
 
Corret = sum(a);
```

This is my code above, and i wish to save the output of the if statement in my list a, how to do so ?

Comment: Are there other values besides `y` and `n`? You could probably just do `a = int(yn_key == KeyResp.keys)`, without an `if`. Anyway, wrap that (or the `if`) in a function, apply it to all answers, collect those in a list and `sum`.

Comment: This is seriously one of the first things covered by the Python introduction: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: am very new in python, am used to MATLAB thats why am not good. 
there are other values than y and n. here i want to sum over all a 1's. so if there is 50 ones in the a list that means there are 50 right answers. i want the corret to give a number besides 0 and 1

Comment: @BasmaAwad From my experience, just going through beginner tutorials like the one  shared is faster than asking on Stack-Overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please use correct upper case letters next time.

Answer (score 1):

Append to the list, like here:

```
a.append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [] ;

if yn_key=='y' and KeyResp.keys == 'y':
    a = a.append(1);
elif yn_key=='n' and KeyResp.keys == 'n':
    a = a.append(2);

else:
    a=a.append(3);
 
Corret = sum(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append the output and show that list later

```
my_list = []
if yn_key=='y' and KeyResp.keys == 'y':
    my_list.append(a) # a = 1
elif yn_key=='n' and KeyResp.keys == 'n':
    my_list.append(a) # a = 1
else:
    my_list.append(a) # a = 0
Corret = sum(a)
```